# Remove Row under a condition

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `X=[0 1 0 0;0 0 0 1;1 0 0 1]` and i want to remove the rows that have more than one '1' in it.
I already know that `sum(X~=0,2)`removes the row will all zeros. Is there a way to do it without a loop?

Comment: Is it certain that the matrix has only 0s and 1s?

Answer (score 3):

This code will do:

```
 X( sum(X') <= 1 , :)
```

`sum(X') <= 1` will return boolean vector containing `1`'s at indices of rows with one or zero ones.

**Update:**
Thanks, commenters. Instead of `sum(X')`, `sum(X,2)` should be used to avoid problems with single row matrices.

Comment: Instead of `sum(X')` you should use: `sum(X,2)`, otherwise for single-column `n-by-1` matrices the output will be unexpected.